# When does Mishna Berura Yomi start again?

Tags: mishnah-berurah

I am seeing different calendars for Mishna Berura Yomi. The  [Amud Yomi Calendar here](https://mishnaberurayomi.org/pickcalendar.php) does not match up with the [shiurim given here.](https://outorah.org/series/3762/) Which one of these is the more popular calendar to use? And if the OU one, it seems to be nearing the end - does anyone know when it starts again at Siman Aleph?

Comment: The OU site stated they’re following the Dirshu calendar. That one does 5 days a week and Friday and Shabbos are review days. They finish on Thursday Feb 17 and start again Sunday Feb 20

Comment: https://www.dafhalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/2021-Luach-Booklet-5-19-21-SPREADS.pdf